# Permission denied on file execution on Linux Red Hat

Tags: linux, services, permissions

I have installed a custom service on Linux .

The service was installed as root in `/etc/init.d/`.

Now, when I want to start the service, it uses a shell script located elsewhere which belongs to user A and group B. this shell script has executable right for everybody.

so I run `service myService start`, but it gives me permission denied on this shell script.

I'm running under su root.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the actual error message, file structure n(with permission and ownership info showing), and the paths. If you want to filter out usernames and other sensitive info that's fine, but show us the actual commands you're entering, and their output.

Comment: Is the service script itself set to executable?